# Is it necessary to fulton extract deployed vehicle in metal gear solid V?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I wanted to know if fulton extracting deployed vehicle was mandatory to get the vehicle back (which is 10000GMP fee), or, if as buddies, they auto-fulton itselves when coming back in the chopper.

Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Any vehicles deployed will automatically return with you when you exit via the chopper, provided they have not been destroyed.

[**GameFAQs - Do deployed vehicles get lost on mission complete if not fultoned?**](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/718564-metal-gear-solid-v-the-phantom-pain/72436685)

[**GameFAQs - Do we need to fulton deployed vehicles...**](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/718564-metal-gear-solid-v-the-phantom-pain/72433331)

[**Reddit - Regarding the vehicles you deploy with into missions**](https://www.reddit.com/r/metalgearsolid/comments/3nmjvo/mgsv_gameplay_regarding_the_vehicles_you_deploy/)

Comment: I believe you can also put unconscious solders in the vehicle for "free" recovery when it auto-fultons itself.